# Using map algebra get minumum and maximum value in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, map-algebra

I am looking for an easy solutions with Map Algebra for this one without Saving:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/temp"

# Set local variables
inRaster = "DOM.tif"
inMask = "Mask.shp"
maskBuffer = "C:/temp/maskBuffer.shp"
temp = "C:/temp/temp.tif"

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inMask, maskBuffer, "5 Meters")


outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, maskBuffer)
#is it possible to get the Minumum and Maximum directly from this Map Algebra?
outExtractByMask.save(temp)

tempRaster = Raster(outExtractByMask)
print(tempRaster.minumum)
```

This is a try to get the height of buildings in a loop, so I will ExtractByMask for each Feature in maskBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

`outExtractByMask` is a `Raster` object, no need to use `tempRaster = Raster(outExtractByMask)`.

[`Raster`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) objects have `minimum` and `maximum` properties.

You just need to [calculate statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) to ensure those properties are not `None`.

```
outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(inRaster, maskBuffer)
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(outExtractByMask)
print(outExtractByMask.minumum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question doesn’t explicitly ask for it, based on the description of your problem you may prefer to use [Zonal Statistics As Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) with your building footprints as zones (with a unique identifier field value for each building), with the “MIN_MAX” statistic.

That would avoid the requirement for looping. Just perform the zonal statistics operation and join the resulting table back to your building footprint layer.